# Entity framework: ObjectContext get generated SQL change script?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-scripts

Is there a way to get all the SQL change script of the object context?

Note: I am not talking about ObjectQuery.ToTraceString();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No unfortunately there isn't anything 'in' the product and available directly off the ObjectContext.

However you should take a look at Jarek's TracingProvider, that injects a layer between the EF and SqlClient to do logging etc.

Read about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution is really amazing, and helps us reduce statement length and amount of queried data. I described the integration of EFTracingProvider on my blog http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/tracing-sql-statements-generated-by-entity-framework/

Comment: If this is true, then how do you think LINQPad, for instance, show all the generated SQL when I run a C# program with an EF ObjectContext? Do you think it also just has some smart engineering similar to TracingProvider to get that to work?